# Is this usage of "short-lived" common?

Tags: nominalizations

In a [Last Week Tonight's segment on Ashley Madison, a married dating site,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzeWC3bdryo) you can see John Oliver saying

> “Life is short. Have an affair. That is the most morally dubious slogan since Toyota’s short-lived, ‘Feeling bored? Hit someone with your car!’ ”

[image: TOYOTA]

If I am not wrong, "Toyota's short-lived" refers to the slogan here. That would mean short-lived is a nominalized adjective.

> Do you still remember Tom's short-lived? (meaning of it depends on the context. It can be his short-lived hobby, short-lived endeavor, or short-lived job, etc)

Is such usage of *short-lived* common (like the word *poor* is common for undergoing nominalization)?

If *short-lived* here is not a nominalized adjective, then I have another question:

Should the comma before ‘Feeling bored? Hit someone with your car!’ be omitted?

Comment: Short-lived: 
adj.
Living or lasting only a short time; ephemeral. It is quite common. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/short-lived. Short-lived refers to 'Feeling bored?'  a slogan that, apparently, was not successful. No I would not use a coma because short-lived just refers to the expression that follows.

Answer (score 2):

"Lived" here means "lifed," or given a span of life, so it's really an "adjectified" noun.

Yes, the comma should be omitted, since it's a modifier of the quotation.  The comma should be present if the phrasing were that of an appositive:

> That is as morally dubious as Toyota’s short-lived slogan, "Feeling
>   bored? Hit someone with your car!"

Be fair, though.  This is a transcription of speech, and speech doesn't have commas.

Answer (score 2):

That part of the phrase in quotes is a citation. Citations can have the same function in sentences as noun phrases do and can also appear as the Heads of their own noun phrases too:

- "*Would if I could*" is an annoying phrase. (Citation as Subject)
- Your quiet "*don't*" was much more effective than my aggressive "*DON'T YOU DARE!*". (Citations as heads of noun phrases)

**The Original Poster's Question**

> ... Toyota’s short-lived ‘*Feeling bored? Hit someone with your car!’

*Short-lived* is not the Head of a noun phrase here. It is an Attributive Modifier inside the larger noun phrase:

- Toyota’s short-lived ‘*Feeling bored? Hit someone with your car!’*

The Head of this phrase is the citation *'Feeling ... car'*. It has a genitive NP, *Toyota's* in Determiner function. And as described it has it's own Attributive Modifier *short-lived*. The Original Poster is right that the comma in the original example is not very helpful. This is precisely because it splits the adjective from the item that it's modifying.

[**Note**: The syntactic functions are capitalised here to distinguish them from word or phrase categories.]